# How to delay revalidate call for workbox StaleWhileRevalidate strategy

Tags: workbox

We are using workbox for implementing ServiceWorker for our webApp.
Currently we are using `workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate` for the homepage route.

The network usage pattern for our app is: Homepage, Javascript resources, API calls (in this order). The Service worker would respond to the homepage with stale data and Javascript resources and API data would be fetched over the network.

We are observing that the revalidate call for homepage is triggered immediately after the request has been served from the cache. So it doesn't help in reducing the contention for network resource. Is there a way to delay the revalidate call for request which is using staleWhileRevalidate strategy? The goal is to reduce network contention before the page load is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delay the revalidation. Theoretically, we could add in a call to a Promise-wrapped `setTimeout()` with a small interval, and make sure to include that in the `event.waitUntil()` to prevent the service worker from terminating in the meantime, but honestly, that doesn't offer any guarantees that there won't be contention—it just pushed the contention out for a small interval of time.

I think a cleaner approach is, in the future, to make use of [Priority Hints](https://wicg.github.io/priority-hints/), and explicitly mark the revalidation request as having `importance: 'low'`. I've added that use case to [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1855) tracking Workbox's use of Priority Hints in general.